# Driver python for postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, driver

Which is the best driver in python to connect to postgresql?

There are a few possibilities, http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Python but I don't know which is the best choice

Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) - it offers great flexibility and has a sophisticated inteface.

Futhermore it's not bound to postgresql alone.

Shameless c&p from the [tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# an Engine, which the Session will use for connection
# resources
some_engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/')

# create a configured "Session" class
Session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)

# create a Session
session = Session()

# work with sess
myobject = MyObject('foo', 'bar')
session.add(myobject)
session.commit()
```

---

Clarifications due to comments (update):

[sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) itself is not a driver, but a so called *Object Relational Mapper*. It does provide and include it's own drivers, which in the postgresql-case is [libpq](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq.html), which itself is wrapped in [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/).

Because the OP emphasized he wanted the "best driver" to "**connect** to postgresql" i pointed sqlalchemy out, even if it might be a false answer terminology-wise, but intention-wise i felt it to be the more useful one.

And even if i do not like the "hair-splitting" dance, i still ended up doing it nonetheless, due to the pressure felt coming from the comments to my answer.

I apologize for any irritations caused by my slander.

Comment: You still need a driver which sqlalchemy is not?

Comment: the batteries are included. The driver would be a database-engine which sqlalchemy provides. atm afaik these are: sqlite, postgresql, mysql, firebird, drizzle, oracle, and some others. no additional packages are required.

Comment: If sqlchemy can do the abstraction to database engine, I think that give me more flexibility and scalability for the future. The question of performance in my case is not a critical issue.

A python native driver will give me more powerful tool to data access but all nasty work will be my responsibility.

I think that I will sacrifice performance to not reinvent the wheel

Comment: The answer seems to me inappropriate. Sqlalchemy is very good app but it is not driver anyway.

Comment: In all due respect, but the term "driver" in almost every database-connection related context is way too ambiguous and mostly used incorrectly. A driver provides an API, which translates and handles connections to the underlying resource. The most often used PostgreSQL-"python driver" "psycopg2" itself utilizes the native C-driver "libpq", to provide a DBAPI 2.0 interface to the developer. So because the OP did focus on the "connection" and "best" is most ambiguous without criteria i interpreted best as "easiest" and "driver" as "interface". Obviously it was exactly what he meant.

Comment: This is not an answer. SqlAlchemy is an ORM. Whether it includes a driver or not it's irrelevant. 

And no, the term "driver" is not "way too ambiguous".

Comment: I beg to differ! The Psycopg2-people point out, that they do not provide a "driver", but an adapter to the DB API 2.0 specifications for the libpq driver in the form of a python-wrapper! But everyone else call psycopg2 a driver (e.g.: Skylar Saveland's answer), which is not really accurate. So i really hate to do the "split hair" thing, but tried to give an answer to what i thought the OP wanted instead of what he asked literally in the first place. But to avoid useless and endless discussions on the meaning of "driver" i updated my answer, to elaborate the reasoning.

Comment: its not a driver dude.

Answer (score 15):

psycopg2 is the one everyone uses with CPython. For PyPy though, you'd want to look at the pure Python ones.

Comment: There is a good talk about running Django on PyPy: http://blip.tv/djangocon-europe-2011/monday-1400-alex-gaynor-good-5343953